# How to set up a staging apt repository to securely manage upgrades

Tags: apt, repository

I would like to be able to run automatic apt-get upgrade (once per hour) on our servers (Ubuntu 10.04), so that I don't have to do it manually on all of them (about 15). However, for production machines, that's not a good idea ...

So here's my idea:

Set up a local repository for all 'approved' updates for critical packages. I would then push updated packages from upstream to our local repo after I tested them, and all servers could automatically (apt-cron?) upgrade from this repository.

So my question is this: How do I configure apt on the clients so that they use the local repository *only* for all packages which exist on the local repository, and the upstream one for all other packages?

Does this actually make sense? Or am I missing something?

Anyways, thanks for your insight!

Andreas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert but I think you can do the with apt pinning.

if you have a local repo at `http://my.local.repo/` called `myrepo`

then your `/etc/apt/sources.list` on you servers will look like this

```
deb http://my.local.repo/ myrepo main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
```

then in the `/etc/apt/preferences` will look like this

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=myrepo
Pin-Priority: 700

Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: 600
```

then `apt` will favour the packets from you local repo

hope this make sense and/or works